# Multiple instances of standalone installer

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-update, windows-installer

So the company I am working at has multiple Vm's that need patching. Mainly Windows Server 2008. A lot of the updates are blocked due to them causing issues on the build systems. However the production systems need the applied updates. My question then, is there a way to update multiple windows updates from Microsoft's website without running the Standalone Installer which takes forever to run? This is working out to be a rather time consuming and tedious process.

Any suggestions or advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If all your vm's are part of a domain,  or even if they aren't setup wsus on one server and then either apply a group policy object that makes computers get updates from that wsus server,  or update each vm local group policy to update from wsus server,  then it will streamline the updates you choose to authorise. That what you looking for?

Comment: So they are on the same domain. and wsus is setup but the updates filtered as to which are allowed to the systems. So I don't want to touch the  wsus server as its been configured that way for a reason. I would like to be-able to apply patches to sever machines yet the standalone installer runs before each update, how do i avoid or suppress that from starting every time I download and install a patch.

Comment: Can you not create computer groups,  and then based on which updates you need (assuming different servers need different ones) you can push the updates to the specific servers and it won't touch the rest.  Or have I got the complete wrong end of the stick?

Comment: No you are correct but there are still patches that are not being pushed through as they need to be manually downloaded and installed.. So for instance I have a system that is on a wsus that allows all updates to be pushed through and installed. Yet when the Qualys scan is ran numerous updates still show up needing to be manually downloaded and installed.

Comment: From the sounds of that your WSUS isn't running properly